# SqlException: invalid column name even though it's not the column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert basic data into my MSSQL database but I keep receiving this error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid column name 'Common'.
Invalid column name 'Bug'.
Invalid column name 'sac'.
Invalid column name 'sacas'.'
```

My query string is:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO dbo.RNMCommits ([Function], Date, Severity, ChangedBy, Changes)";
query += string.Format(" VALUES ({0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4})", function, date, severity, changedBy, changes);
```

I do not understand the exception, it says that column names `Common, Bug, sac, sacas` are invalid, but I am not using these as column names. I am stating in the INSERT statement that it should use `([Function], Date, Severity, ChangedBy, Changes)";` and insert VALUES `VALUES ({0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4})", function, date, severity, changedBy, changes)` which is `common, bug, sac and scas.`

These values are strings:

```
string function = comboBoxEdit_Function.SelectedItem.ToString();
string severity = comboBoxEdit_Severity.SelectedItem.ToString();
string changedBy = textEdit_ChangedBy.Text;
string date = dateEdit_Date.Text;
string changes = memoEdit_Changes.Text;
```

The whole method that gets executed:

```
    private void simpleButton_OK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string function = comboBoxEdit_Function.SelectedItem.ToString();
    string severity = comboBoxEdit_Severity.SelectedItem.ToString();
    string changedBy = textEdit_ChangedBy.Text;
    string date = dateEdit_Date.Text;
    string changes = memoEdit_Changes.Text;

    SqlConnection cnn;
    string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=L3T_Project_Assistent;User ID=xx;Password=xx";
    cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    cnn.Open();

    string query = "INSERT INTO dbo.RNMCommits ([Function], Date, Severity, ChangedBy, Changes)";
    query += string.Format(" VALUES ({0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4})", function, date, severity, changedBy, changes);

    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, cnn);
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cnn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried placing single quotes around each of your variable values? `string.Format(" VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}')",`

Comment: Include the code that executes the query, may be the issues with the executing command, which hold previous queries

Comment: Using parameters instead of concatenation will alleviate most of this. Also, I think `Date` will need to be wrapped too like you did with `Function`

Comment: parameterize your query and you'll never have this issue.

Comment: If in your list of value there is a value for string type column and it is missing single quotes at starting and ending of the value, the value than treated as a column name and through a similar type of error.

Comment: @RyanWilson thanks it worked by putting single quotes!

Comment: @asp.netCoreProblem Glad to help, I added as an answer if you want to accept it, thank you.

Comment: I will as soon as it lets me accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When passing `varchar/nvarchar/text` values you need to wrap them in single quotes:

```
string.Format(" VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}')"
```

Comment: I'm no C# guru, but the industry standard of using SQL in application layer is parameterization, avoiding string concatenation, quote enclosure, type handling, and sql injection.

Comment: @Parfait Yep, but that wasn't what the OP asked.

Comment: Understood but StackOverflow is well-developed by now that we should recommend best practices. Missing quotes is very simple overlook. OP and future readers may be new to C#, SQL, programming. In fact, values appear to be coming from a user interface, exposing this solution to SQL injection (i.e., [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)).

Comment: @Parfait I believe best practices are mentioned multiple times in the comments, if the OP is going to listen to the advice of others, then they will move to a parameterized approach. I am simply giving them an answer to the question posted, if they want advice on design, they should ask it in a question.